# Why is the text of this answer gray?

Tags: discussion, design, markdown

Why is the text-color of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528591/how-to-number-the-datas-from-mysql/2528599#2528599) gray instead of black?

I don't see what's special about it - except for the fact that it is an exact duplicate of [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528591/how-to-number-the-datas-from-mysql/2528602#2528602) to the same question.

---

[alt text http://img84.imageshack.us/img84/5294/grayanswer.png](http://img84.imageshack.us/img84/5294/grayanswer.png)

---

Comment: I suspect it will soon be the "deleted" color...

Comment: It lets the user know when their Peer Pressure badge is ready.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Posts are greyed out or dimmed when their total displaying score falls to **-3** or lower.