# The flag dialog under bad posts has gray text

Tags: bug, user-interface, design, flag-dialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The flag pop up on heavily downvoted answers has grey text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40111/the-flag-pop-up-on-heavily-downvoted-answers-has-grey-text)

When answers get downvoted enough, their text [turns gray](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44248/why-is-the-text-of-this-answer-gray). Unfortunately, the gray text style carries over to the flag dialog. The dialog has done nothing wrong, and it's hard to read gray on gray. Please don't have the bad post style carry over. Screenshot:

[image: flag dialog with gray text]